# When using generators with Keras, what does the X in n/X represent that's printed out for each epoch

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, theano

When using fit generators and when setting verbose to 1, Keras prints the following (below). I'm working with 14,753 input images and have allocated 80% to training and 20% to testing. The batch size is 32.

Sometimes I understand how X works.  When you multiply out 14,753 observations * 80% for training / 32 (batch size) you get 368 which is sometimes what shows for X. I suspect this number represents the number of times data from the generator is yielded. But other times, when training on deeper more complex models, X is much higher and shows seemingly arbitrary numbers > 1000. **How is X calculated then?**

**Epoch 1**

1/10  (1=n, X=10)

2/10

3/10

etc.

**Epoch 2**

1/10

2/10

3/10
etc.

---

**Neural net 1 (X = 368 which makes sense)**

```
activation_function = 'relu'
epoch_count = 20
loss_function = 'mean_squared_error'
opt = 'adam'

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=inp_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=inp_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32, activation=activation_function))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_targets))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss=loss_function, optimizer=opt)

hist = model.fit_generator(
    generator(imgIds, batch_size=batch_size, is_train=True),
    validation_data=generator(imgIds, batch_size=batch_size, is_val=True), validation_steps=steps_per_val,
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    epochs=epoch_count,
    verbose=verbose_level)
```

**Neural net 2 (X = 1602 which I don't understand)**

```
activation_function = 'relu'
batch_size = 32  # ##
steps_per_epoch = int(len(imgIds) * 0.8 / batch_size)
steps_per_val = int(len(imgIds) * 0.2 / batch_size)
epoch_count = 20
loss_function = 'mean_squared_error'
opt = 'adam'

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=inp_shape, activation=activation_function))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation=activation_function))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation=activation_function))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation=activation_function))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation=activation_function))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation=activation_function))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation=activation_function))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation=activation_function))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(300, activation=activation_function))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(Dense(200, activation=activation_function))
model.add(Dense(num_targets))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss=loss_function, optimizer=opt)

hist = model.fit_generator(
    generator(imgIds, batch_size=batch_size, is_train=True),
    validation_data=generator(imgIds, batch_size=batch_size, is_val=True), validation_steps=steps_per_val,
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    epochs=epoch_count,
    verbose=verbose_level)
```

Comment: Isn't it `steps_per_epoch`?

Comment: It is for the simple model but for the more complex one it shows a higher number. That's if steps_per_epoch is defined as described in my question.. @DanielMöller